# Fetching external url images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, get-request

I want to fetch the images[] array of an external URL. I was able to retrieve the actual source code of the page using $.ajax, but I don't know how to access the images.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
var images = [];
$(pagecode).find('img').each(function(){
   images.push( this.src );
});
```

Comment: Amazingly you posted the exact same answer as I wanted to, including all text in the answer and the code, anyways, this is a correct answer

Comment: @Torben :) (*i swear i didn't steal it :p*)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `img` tag, set src to the actual url of image, then append to a specific place:

```
$('<img/>').attr('src', 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png').appendTo('body')
```

Comment: The problem is that i need to find the particular img url inside a big html source code.

Comment: I don't think this is a correct answer, the author seems to want to read the srcs from HTML, not settings them for single tags

Answer (score 1):

You can use **.load()** method.
The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows you to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted.

```
$('#result').load('http://www.mypage.com/myimages.htm img');
```

That will load every image on the page.